# how to count directories in unix?

Tags: count, ls

I am running the fallowing command "ls | wc -l" to count file and to count directories.
the command

I am looking at how to count the total images in all directories with in a folder.
Also how do I count only images with in all directories

Answer (score 0):

Find is what You need.
To count both files and folders with sub-directories You can just use:

```
find /directory/  | wc -l
```

If You need to count only files i those sub-directories You have to add type filter:

```
find /directory/ -type f  | wc -l
```

Comment: when I run this command” find */  | wc -l” I get all images in all dir I get 9
Then when I run find */ -type f | wc -l I get 7
I should have 2 dir and 9 tif images

Comment: Are You sure, that You want to use */ instead ./ ? 
*/ is omitting current directory and files in it.

Comment: when i with ./ ? */ I get ?. When I tryed find ./ */ | wc -l I get 23. I need to have a count of 2

Comment: You mean that You want to count only directories? 
Then try -type d 
This will count only directories without files.